# Find the only common word from two strings in c++

Tags: c++, string, substring

I need to return a string from a function that include the common word of two strings (given that there is only one common word).
I can use the functions `strcmp`, `strlen`, `strcat` and `strcpy`.
I managed when the first word in the strings are identical, but if it's after that, it doesn't work.

**Example that doesn't work:**

```
str1[] = {"Hello world"}; //string 1

str2[] = {"Thanks you world"}; // string 2

Example that work:

char str1[] = {"Hello world"}; //string 1

char str2[] = {"Hello Danny"}; // string 2
```

**Here is my code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
# include <string.h>
char * Strcom(char str1[], char str2[]); //declare function
int main()
{
    char str1[] = { "Hello world" }; //string 1
    char str2[] = { "Thanks you world" }; // string 2
    Strcom(str1, str2);
}
char * Strcom(char str1[], char str2[])
{
    char temp[10];
    int i = 0, z = 0;
    while (i <= strlen(str1))//run over str1, copying word in the next while loop
    {
        int k = 0;
        bool check = 0;
        while ((z < strlen(str2)) && (k < strlen(temp)))//check that I withing the lenght...
        {
            char temp[10] = { 0 };
            while ((str1[i] != ' ')&&(i<10))//copy one word to temp from str1
            {
                temp[i] = str1[i];
                i++;
            }
            if (i != strlen(temp))
            {
                temp[i] = '\0';
            }
            else
                temp[i-1] = '\0';
            i++;//to jump over ' '
            while (str2[z] != ' ') //check if its the same world (temp and str2)
            {
                if (temp[k] == str2[z])
                {
                    k++, z++;
                    check = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    check = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (((str2[z] == ' ') || (str2[z] == '\0')) && (check == 1))//its the same word
            {
                temp[k] = '\0';//to be able to print it
                cout <<"my word is: " <<temp<< endl;
                return temp;
            }
            z += 1;
            k = 10;//to go to the outer while loop
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: If there is only one common word and you already found it, why do you think you are stuck?

Comment: I meant that when the first word in the two string are identical its working, but if its the 2 or 3 word it doesn't...

Comment: Please update your post with examples that worrk and examples that don't work. That will be helpful for those who look at your code.

Comment: Too bad about your instructors arbitrary function restrictions. `std::istringstream` and `std::unordered_set<std:string>` with an iterator-range construction and a single-pass loop would make this into about six lines of code.  Ironic they have you using a set of functions most C++ engineers avoid in daily use. Resist the urge to tell them if you wanted a course in C you would have signed up for one.

Comment: They are trying to teach us c and c++ at the same time

Comment: @Begginer No offense, but that's idiotic on their part. The fact that the two languages share a subset syntax isn't grounds to do that. Each one is hard enough on its own, and the general system of utilizing the standard library for each rapidly diverges any syntax commonalities. A C programmer would do what they seem to want; a C++ programmer would do what I described. Obviously they're very, *very* different things. Doesn't mean you can't do the former in C++ (the language and lib do, after all, support it), but you honestly wouldn't if you had the C++ standard lib at your disposal.

Comment: good that you added the examples, but what exactly "doesnt work" ? What is the output you get for the non-working example?

Comment: Actually I got nothing as an output...
but when I run debbug, I got this announcment:

"Unhandled exception at 0x00232BF7 in Proj5.exe: RangeChecks instrumentation code detected an out of range array access."
The problem is, I dont know exactly where...

Comment: @WhozCraig "No offence" is a meaningless qualifier. I'm done with being polite about people who think it's OK to teach *bad C++* (and quite likely *bad C*) with the rationalisation that "then they are interchangeable"

Comment: temp[i]='\0' => i may be 10, and temp[10] is not a valid index.

Comment: str2[z] == '/0' => should be str2[z] == '\0'

Comment: k=5; => Why do you think that each word is 5 characters long?

Comment: thanks for answering, I have tried your changes, but it still didnt solve it.
About k=5, I did it in order to return to the outer while loop...

Comment: @Caleth I meant no offense to the OP. The designers of the curriculum, on the other hand, should be flogged.

Answer (score 0):

If you need C-style C++ code for learning instead of production, the required functionality can be solved something like this:

```
bool CommonWord( const char* words_a, const char* words_b, char* result )
{
    // Iterate throught the words of words_a
    while( IsolateWord( words_a, result ) )
    {
        // Start from the beginning of words_b
        const char* word_list = words_b;
        while( *word_list != '\0' )
        {
            // See if words match
            int eaten = 0;
            if( CompareWord( result, words_b, &eaten ) )
            {
                // Success, the matching word was copied to result before
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                // Go to the beginning of the next word or the end of the string
                for( word_list += eaten; ( *word_list != ' ' ) && ( *word_list != '\0' ); word_list++ )
                {
                    ;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // No matching words found, empty result
    result[ 0 ] = '\0';
    return false;
}

bool IsolateWord( const char* words, char* result )
{
    // Skip leading spaces
    const char* start = words;
    while( *start == ' ' )
    {
        start++;
    }

    // Find end of word
    const char* end = start;
    while( ( end != ' ' ) && ( end != '\0' ) )
    {
        end++;
    }

    // No more word
    if( end == start )
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Copy word to buffer
    while( *start != '\0' )
    {
        *result++ = *start++;
    }
    *result = '\0';
    return true;
}

bool CompareWord( const char* word_one, const char* word_list, int* eaten )
{
    // Go until characters differ or strings end
    for( *eaten = 0; ( word_one[ *eaten ] == word_list[ *eaten ] ) && ( word_one[ *eaten ] != '\0' ); ( *eaten )++ )
    {
        ;
    }

    // If reached end of word_one, and word_list contains the same characters plus a space or '\0', then the word matches
    if( ( word_one[ *eaten ] == '\0' ) && ( ( word_list[ *eaten ] == ' ' ) ||  ( word_list[ *eaten ] == '\0' ) ))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Warning: I don't have a C or C++ compiler at hand, so I did not even compile the above.

Comment: To tell the hard truth, I learn almost two degrees at the same time, so the answer was too late for me and I don't  and didn't as well have the time to check if the suggested code its working.